# What is Causing a Java Class to be Loaded?

Tags: java, classloader

I am trying to open a Java class file, instrument the bytecode and save the class file before the class is loaded into the JVM.  My problem is that a class is being loaded "too soon" into the JVM.  The bytecode is instrumented after the class is loaded into the JVM.

`-verbose:class` prints when each class is loaded but it doesn't tell me what triggered the JVM to load the class.  How do I get a call stack which shows the class being loaded?

Putting a breakpoint in the following code, shows the call stack when the class is initialized and not loaded.

```
static
{
    System.out.println("Initialized!");
}
```

Note: I know I could use a Java agent to do this and guarantee the bytecode is instrumented.  But, I choose this route for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened `java.lang.ClassLoader` and set a conditional breakpoint in `loadClass(String name, boolean resolve)`.  The condition is `arg0.endsWith("MyClass")` where `arg0` is the `name` parameter.  When the breakpoint is triggered, the IDE displays the call stack.  Several frames down on the call stack shows me why the class is being loaded.

Note: This condition works in Eclipse IDE and may need a little tweaking in other IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

On the Hotspot JVM, which is what is used with the the Oracle and OpenJDK java distributions, classes are loaded when they are first referenced.  Here are the relevant snippets from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html

> The Java Virtual Machine starts up by creating an initial class, which is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the bootstrap class loader (§5.3.1). The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it, and invokes the public class method void main(String[]). The invocation of this method drives all further execution. Execution of the Java Virtual Machine instructions constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation of additional methods.
>
> Creation of a class or interface C denoted by the name N consists of the construction in the method area of the Java Virtual Machine (§2.5.4) of an implementation-specific internal representation of C. Class or interface creation is triggered by another class or interface D, which references C through its run-time constant pool. Class or interface creation may also be triggered by D invoking methods in certain Java SE platform class libraries (§2.12) such as reflection.

If you wish to actually perform the bytecode manipulation yourself, and at runtime, then there are at least two models that you may choose to follow

1. Use something akin to AspectJ's load time weaving, which involves using a separate classloader and an agent to respond to class loading
2. How JRebel does it, via monitoring known .class files for updated timestamps http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/faq/

Unless you have a very strong need to do this yourself however, consider using one of the above mentioned tools.  Better yet, determine if Java annotations and reflection can solve what you are attempting to do instead.

Comment: This answer in its current form tells me about class loading.  But, it doesn't answer the question "How do I get a call stack which shows the class being loaded?"

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can't reliably determine what actually caused a class to load without always controlling the ClassLoader used to load a given class.  You can't rely on a static initializer, as those only execute when a new instance is created, or a static field/method are accessed.